# Display running time while a method is running in python

Tags: python, methods, ipython

I have a method that takes long time to run. It has no iterables to use any progress bars like `tqdm`. While running, I would like it to display time elapsed with some progress graphic (something similar to package installers in Unix/Linux systems do with rotating `/` or some graphic `...`). In the following dummy code

```
from time import sleep

def longTimetakingmethod():
    sleep(3600)
    showgraphictime()

longTimetakingmethod()
```

The `showgraphictime()` method should cause display something like

`Calculating.../ Time elapsed: 00 hrs:15 mins:05 s`

Is there a simple way to implement `showgraphictime()` ?

Or does it have to be a wrapper like `showrunningupdate(longTimetakingmethod())`

```
from time import sleep

def longTimetakingmethod():
    sleep(3600)

showrunningupdate(longTimetakingmethod())
```

Comment: I was missing functionality like this too, so I added it to the terminal spinner package that I use (yaspin). It's fairly straightforward, see the [pull request here](https://github.com/pavdmyt/yaspin/pull/99)

Answer (score 1):

This library could be useful for you: [Beautiful terminal spinners in Python](https://github.com/ManrajGrover/halo)

Example:

```
from halo import Halo
from time import sleep

def rocket_launch():
    spinner = Halo({'spinner': 'shark'})
    spinner.start()
    for c in range(10, 0, -1):
        spinner.text = 'Launching in {} seconds'.format(c)
        sleep(1)
    spinner.succeed('Rocket launched')

rocket_launch()
```

Comment: Interesting library... Certainly solves the first part. How do I get time elapsed in runtime I wonder...

Comment: `start = time.time(); do_something(); elapsed = time.time()-start` measurement in seconds.

Comment: @VPfB This shows total time elapsed once the run is finished. I am looking for something that shows time while running.

Comment: @pbacterio Thank you! Your example is when we can fix the total time. But most methods, we don't know the total time it is going to take. I am looking to see the time elapsed while running incrementally.

Comment: @RohinKumar I'm sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: `snipper.text` is arbitrary, you can put elapsed time as shows @VPfB

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timeit module to map time taken for that and one of the spinners as suggested by @pbacterio

Comment: Doesn't `timeit` module show the total time spent in execution of a module? I am looking for something that shows time while it is running.